# Custom css file for jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I would like to use custom .css style file for my jupyter notebook inside jupyterHub. I placed the `custom.css` file inside `~.jupyter/custom/custom.css` and `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/custom` and neither of them works. Any idea how to force custom css style when using DockerSpawner?

Comment: This directory `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`,  did mean on jupyterhub container or jupyter-notebook (user) container.  `cutsom` folder must be on user container.

Comment: @saurssaurav it is on the user container

Comment: I had my custom folder in user container like `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` . And its running perfectly taking all custom css.
Did you check inside container if custom folder exist ?

Comment: @saurssaurav I will check it once again later and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late to help OP, but leaving here for future dwellers:

I placed my `custom.css` and `custom.js` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/static/custom/` and it worked perfectly.

NB I don't use conda, and I use the default (Local) spawner instead of DockerSpawner (if that's relevant).

Answer (score 0):

The  location for "Anaconda3 , Windows10, Everyone to Access" is
c:\programData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.css

We may look for ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css . if it does not exist,  we can create one. However,  since it is just created, we need to restart the notebook to be effective. Afterwards,  we may simply change the contents of the file anytime without restarting the notebook.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.